# Как перебрать масив с конца?

Tags: php, массивы, ооп, event-loop

Есть массив с ценой и датой. Нужно прогнать его через цикл, чтобы с конца все было и только последних 3 массива. Кто знает как? (вариант с `if($c++ == 3)` не подходит)

```
$arr = [
     ['2019-01-01', '12'],['2019-01-02', '12'],['2019-01-03', '12'],
     ['2019-01-04', '12'],['2019-01-05', '12'],['2019-01-06', '12'],
     ['2019-01-07', '12']
];
foreach($arr as $values){
    echo $values[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычный цикл for  как раз тут и сгодится

```
$cnt = 3;
for ($i=count($arr)-1; $i>=count($arr)-$cnt; $i--) {
     $values = $arr[$i];
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc01f1cc555aee7daed82a08e800414b2f767605)

Comment: А что тут делает `$i++`?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function len()

Это случайно не с джс?
я думал также о array_slice но как взять елементы с конца ... при том что массив у меня динамичный

Comment: поправил. array_slice тоже можно, чтобы выбрать последних три, но порядок им не изменить

Answer (score 0):

array_reverse — возвращает массив с элементами в обратном порядке ([ссылка](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php))

```
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
```

Comment: `foreach (array_reverse(array_slice($arr, -3)) as $values) {`